# How to make WPF ComboBox default selection to blank

Tags: wpf-controls

I have an `enum` like:

```
enum Gender
{
   Male = 1,
   Female = 2
}
```

Then I have a `Combobox` binding to a list of `Gender`.

```
<ComboBox ItemSource = 'Binding GenderList, Mode=TwoWay,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged'
          SelectItem = 'Binding SelectedGender' />
```

When user opens the view, how can I make `ComboBox` selection default to blank? Then after user made a selection, the blank selection is removed from the `ComboBox` source.

Thanks

---

Thanks all the replies. I fixed my problem by manully assigning the selected item to null.

Comment: Please make sure your XAML works to start with - there are no such properties as `ItemSource` or `SelectItem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is the default behavior of the ComboBox.  You don't need to do anything (except for correct the typos in your XAML.  It should look like:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding GenderList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedGender}" ></ComboBox>
```

Comment: Hi Greg. thanks for your reply. I tried your code, but it still displays the first item in the list instead of blank item.

Comment: @Jing: Try removing the `SelectedItem` attribute.